# Unable to merge dex при добавлении play-services

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

Столкнулся с проблемой [в этом уроке.](http://www.fandroid.info/kak-sozdat-prilozhenie-dlya-schityvaniya-shtrih-koda-na-android/).

При добавлении строчки в gradle:

```
compile  'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
```

Получил ошибку

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.0.0, 24.0.0. Examples include `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0` and `com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0`

Покопавшись в интернете нашел решение и добавил в gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0'
```

Теперь при компиляции проекта получаю ошибку:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Проект пытаюсь запустить на Android 4.0.4. Gradle целиком:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.aseng.barcodetry"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile  'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile  'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `clean` и `rebuild project`.

Comment: Вам не нужны все play services в проекте. Это очень большая библиотека с кучей методов, которые у вас не влезают в один dex файл. Что оттуда вы используете? Посмотрите [тут](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) какие есть зависимости для play services и как правильно их добавлять в проект.

Comment: eugeneek, спасибо, Ваш совет помог, я заменил play services на Mobile Vision и все заработало.